# MySQL trigger will not work, no error

Tags: mysql

So I created a trigger to update another table on an insert, no errors found and the trigger exists(gets listed in  `SHOW TRIGGERS`, but there is no update to the other table after I insert to one.

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER setmapsquare AFTER INSERT ON users

FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE map SET player_id = NEW.player_id WHERE map_id = NEW.startsquare;
```

It throws no errors, so I do not now how to proceed :/

EDIT: also the insert takes place here:

```
$q = $DBC -> prepare( "
    INSERT INTO 
        users 
    ( username, password, email, startsquare ) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, (SELECT map_id FROM map WHERE player_id IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) );" );
```

The inserted row `1, 'Testjuuser', '2bd7fc520207eabc4026989728def05b541a863e', 'test@test', 38, 2014-08-31 09:20:28, 0, 0`

and the map_id 38 still has NULL as its player_id

Comment: It looks like your WHERE clause filters out all rows of the map table.

Comment: That is weird, because in the new row the startsquare is clearly marked. and that value exists in the map table because I selected it to be there: ´`$q = $DBC -> prepare( "
        INSERT INTO 
            users 
        ( username, password, email, startsquare ) 
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, (SELECT map_id FROM map WHERE player_id IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) );" );´`

Comment: I recommend activating the general query log for debugging this issue.

Comment: I will try. I tried the trigger with `UPDATE map SET player_id = 1 WHERE map_id = NEW.startsquare;` and it did not get updated either, so it's probably the where clause

Comment: Neither did it work without the WHERE clause, for some reason it does not get triggered at all

Comment: If I try to reproduce this I get following error: `Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'map' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: Aha so I need to do a more elaborate way of finding a map square that is empty, maybe post it to answer so I can accept it?

Comment: But you should get this error too - and you said that you get no error. Try it out i.e. with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Where did you get this? I got none, the insert worked, but trigger did not fire, I assumed you used some kind of debugging.

Comment: I created two tables with the columns from your post, and the trigger too. Then I inserted some rows into the map table: Finally I had a try with your INSERT INTO statement using the values from your post and copied the error message I got into the comment. I've got to add that the INSERT statement did fail while you stated that your INSERT succeded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60337/discussion-between-vmai-and-limiter).

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57dee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior as described by the question can't be reproduced. The `INSERT` statement should fail with the error message:

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'map' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Steps to reproduce this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    player_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(20),
    password VARCHAR(80),
    email VARCHAR(260),
    startsquare INT
);

CREATE TABLE map (
    map_id INT,
    player_id INT
);
```

Insert some values for the table map

```
INSERT INTO map (map_id, player_id) VALUES 
(37, NULL),
(38, NULL),
(39, NULL);
```

Create the trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER setmapsquare AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE map SET player_id = NEW.player_id WHERE map_id = NEW.startsquare;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Try this insert

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, startsquare) VALUES
(
    'Testjuuser', 
    '2bd7fc520207eabc4026989728def05b541a863e', 
    'test@test', 
    (SELECT map_id FROM map WHERE player_id IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
);
```

and get the error message shown above, [see this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57dee)

**Note:** You've got to comment out the 38 and remove the dashes before the select.

While the hard coded 38 will processed as expected:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, startsquare) VALUES
(
    'Testjuuser', 
    '2bd7fc520207eabc4026989728def05b541a863e', 
    'test@test', 
    38
);
```

**Conclusion**

Either the actual trigger statement is not that shown in the question or there are errors, but then the INSERT should fail completely. To check the trigger statement one could use following query against the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT 
    trigger_schema,         -- the database,
    event_object_table,     -- table
    action_timing,          -- should be 'after'
    event_manipulation,     -- should be 'INSERT'
    action_statement        -- the actual code
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS 
WHERE 
    trigger_name = 'setmapsquare';
```

The content of action_statement is in my case

```
UPDATE map SET player_id = NEW.player_id WHERE map_id = NEW.startsquare
```

Comment: I will accept to give respect for such thorough answer but it does not behave like this for me. I will change the logic up a bit so I so not have to use a trigger for that. Thank You for the time :)